# Wicket with Javascript application(GWT made by LibGDX)

Tags: gwt, libgdx, wicket

I can read english to some degree but I'm not good at writing.
Then I appologize for any rudeness.

I don't know well about wicket but I think it very good.

I want to deploy on wicket Javascript application made by LibGDX ,but on wicket's HTML file it does not work.

LibGDX logo was shown but next is not.(Maybe it seems to be not found next file (xxxx.cache.html) ??)

Please Tell me how to work Javascript(GWT) application on wicket.

Chrome shows this error.

```
Uncaught        ED5709743BB488EF40123B0ADA51D171.cache.html:84393
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Invalid assets description file.
```

My Javascript application is made by GWT which is client only created by LibGDX.

(LibGDX is multi platform game framework.
It can create WebGL application from java by GWT compiled.)

I think it can work in wicket because this GWT application is client only.

Javascript application is

```
assets
 |...(many files used in game)
   |-com
      |-badlogic
        |-gdx
          |-...(some directory)

html
 |html.nocache.js
 |A0B51A68A37B38F9FF8A8855EDF848C7.cache.html
 |Bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cache.html
 |Cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cache.html
 |ED5709743BB488EF40123B0ADA51D171.cache.html
 |Exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cache.html
 |hosted.html
 |soundmanager2.swf
 |logo.png
 |....(many files)
 |-gwt
   |-chrome
     |chrome_rtl.css
     |chrome.css
     |-images
       |-...(some directory)
       |...(some files)
soundmanager2-jsmin.js
soundmanager2-setup.js
styles.css
```

My Javascript application can work in Struts JSP(deployment under webapp).

I wrote at wicket in this way :

*src/main/java/.../testwicket/page/xxx.html*

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
       <head>
              <title>wicket + gwt(client only) test</title>
              <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
              <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
              <script src="soundmanager2-setup.js"></script>
              <script src="soundmanager2-jsmin.js"></script>
       </head>

       <body>
            <a class="superdev" href="javascript:%7B%20window.__gwt_bookmarklet_params%20%3D%20%7B'server_url'%3A'http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2F'%7D%3B%20var%20s%20%3D%20document.createElement('script')%3B%20s.src%20%3D%20'http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fdev_mode_on.js'%3B%20void(document.getElementsByTagName('head')%5B0%5D.appendChild(s))%3B%7D">SuperDev Refresh</a>
              <div align="center" id="embed-html"></div>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="html/html.nocache.js"></script>
       </body>

       <script>
              function handleMouseDown(evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                evt.stopPropagation();
                evt.target.style.cursor = 'default';
              }

              function handleMouseUp(evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                evt.stopPropagation();
                evt.target.style.cursor = '';
              }
              document.getElementById('embed-html').addEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDown, false);
              document.getElementById('embed-html').addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp, false);
       </script>
</html>
```

Javascript application is in

*src/main/webapp/*

```
|-assets
|-html
soundmanager2-jsmin.js
soundmanager2-setup.js
style.css
```

Even if this code is added in GWT, it do not work(I don't call this code from java...Should I call it?).

```
public static native void setWindowHref(String url)/*-{
     $wnd.location.href = url;
}-*/;
```

Comment: What errors do you experience ?

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay in replying. Checked only the my mailbox for waiting reply.
Thanks replying.

No error in wicket. In chrome, JS error is 
[Uncaught        ED5709743BB488EF40123B0ADA51D171.cache.html:84393
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Invalid assets description file].

Do not start my game.

Comment: Sorry. I have no experience with LibGDX. Hopefully someone else will bring some light.

Comment: I was happy about your response.